# In there a way to combine Windows Authentication with a cookie-based session using Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity

I have a application that is written with C# on the top of ASP.NET MVC 5.

When creating my app in Visual Studio, I set it so it required Windows Authentication. However, each time the browser closes/opened the user is forced to log in/out each time.

I would like to store that session in a cookie somehow so the session lives for 15 minutes even after the browser is closed.

When I created my application using "Windows Authentication" it did not get created with the `IdentityConfig.cs` file.

How can I keep the Windows Authentication session good for 15 minutes?

Comment: That can help http://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/